# What is "prodecure call"?

Tags: terminology

RPC (remote procedure call is a common name), but what's the definition of **procedure call** ?

From [https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/cpu-mechanisms.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/cpu-mechanisms.pdf):

> ###### ASIDE: WHY SYSTEM CALLS LOOK LIKE PROCEDURE CALLS
>
> You may wonder why a call to a system call, such as `open()` or `read()`, looks exactly
> like a typical procedure call in C; that is, if it looks just like a
> procedure call, how does the system know it’s a system call, and do
> all the right stuff? The simple reason: it is a procedure call, but
> hidden inside that procedure call is the famous trap instruction.
> ....

What is the classification? Are there other xxxx calls  classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Procedures is just another name for subroutines/functions.**

From [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (emphasis mine)

> In distributed computing, a remote procedure call (RPC) is when a computer program causes a procedure **(subroutine)** to execute in a different address space (commonly on another computer on a shared network), which is coded as if it were a normal (local) procedure call, without the programmer explicitly coding the details for the remote interaction.

And [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine#:%7E:text=In_computer_programming,_a_subroutine,particular_task_should_be_performed.)

> Subroutines may be defined within programs, or separately in libraries that can be used by many programs. In different programming languages, a **subroutine** may be called a routine, subprogram, function, method, or **procedure**.

**So, procedure calls are just calls to the subroutine/function.** This invokes the steps laid out in the procedure.

From [source](http://www.cs.uni.edu/%7Emccormic/AdaEssentials/procedure_calls.htm)

> A procedure call is a simple statement made by stating the procedure name, listing actual parameter names or values within parentheses, and adding a final semi-colon.